# Does treetabular support remote child nodes?

Tags: reactjs, reactabular

I want to prepare a tree structure using reactabular / treetabular. For every parent node that is to be displayed, I want to show a collapsed parent. But there won't be any child nodes just yet. When the user expands the parent, the child nodes will be retrieved via API call and displayed. How do I do this with [treetabular](https://github.com/reactabular/treetabular)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in support.

That said, you can likely develop this functionality on top of what exists already. To do this, you'll need to track `fetch` state and capture parent interaction (likely `onClick`). You may also need some mock children so you get hide/show control to intercept.

It may be worth it to look into integrating some of this functionality into **treetabular**. But write a proof of concept before that.